# When using natural numbers as array index, will `for (VAR in ARRAY)` iterate in the correct order?

Tags: arrays, indexing, awk

The title says it all:
When I construct an array in `awk` using natural (one-based) numbers as index by appending elements, can I use `for (VAR in ARRAY)` to get the array elements in the correct order (i.e. the order the elements were added)?

As arrays in `awk` are associative, the question is whether the iteration would use the order that `foreach (@array)` would give in Perl, or more likely what `while (my ($k, $v) = each %hash)` would give (also in Perl).
The latter may be any order.

The `gawk` manual states:

> An important aspect to remember about arrays is that *array subscripts
> are always strings*.  When a numeric value is used as a subscript, it is
> converted to a string value before being used for subscripting.

I know that I can construct a `for` loop counting up the index in `awk`, but still I wonder.

Comment: If you are using GNU awk have a look at `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` and its `"@ind_num_asc"` possible value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `in the correct order`? Numerically ascending? Numerically descending? First-in? Alphabetically ascending (since array indices are always strings, not numbers)? Something else?

The point is there is no generally "correct order" so there is no specific order that would be "correct" across all scripts for awk to visit the indices in and so it's up to every awk to simply visit the indices as efficiently as possible.

If you have a set of numeric indices starting at, say, 1 but you don't know the max value and you want to visit them in ascending order, for example, you can do:

```
for (i=1; i in array; i++) {
    print array[i]
}
```

otherwise write your own way of tracking order, e.g. to get them in first-in order (assuming all unique indices):

```
order[++numIndices] = $1
array[$1] = $2
...
for (o=1; o<=numIndices; o++) {
    i = order[o]
    print array[i]
}
```

or use GNU awk for [PROCINFO["sorted_in"]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) but you'd still have to write your own way of tracking first-in order even with that.

Comment: On "correct order": Just read the sentence in the question to the end! I aslo wonder whether `i in array` has complexity O(1) or worse. On `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`: I thought that only applies to the special array `PROCINFO`.

Comment: @U.Windl Yes, I know what the OP thinks is the correct order, my point is there is no one correct order, the correct order is whatever you want it to be for your application. I'm not sure what your last sentence means, sorry - you set `sorted_in` in `PROCINFO[]` to affect the order that the `in` operator visits the elements of any array in a `for (i in array)` loop.

Comment: Sorry: I misunderstood what array `PROCINFO` is used for; I was confused with `/proc` in Linux when actually you can set or query various `awk` internals.

Comment: @U.Windl I undid your edit as I'm not trying to tell people any specific order to select using `sorted_in`, just to use it however they see fit for whatever order they want.

Comment: The question specifically mentioned "natural numbers" being used as indices, so I think "@ind_num_asc" would be the correct setting for the answer (even though the mechanism allows more flexibility for other types of indices).

Comment: @U.Windl the question didn't tell is if they'd want ascending or descending order and in fact they specifically said `the order the elements were added` was the order they expected so `@ind_num_asc` is just 1 possible guess at what would be correct. I just noticed you're the person who posted the question so I suppose you'd have a better guess than most of us!

Comment: Oh well, how would you enumerate 1-based natural numbers?

Comment: Since this question is about arrays I assume you're asking how I'd visit array elements that have natural numbers as array indices, so - ascending numeric index or descending numeric index or first-in or last-in or by the value stored at that index or something else.

Comment: I'm going to stop discussion here, because I think "*When I construct an array in awk using natural (one-based) numbers as index by appending elements*" is a rather obvious description of `a[++i]=e`.

Comment: Could be. Had you provided such code in your question or not waited over 3 months after I answered it (until I had forgotten all about it and had close to no interest in re-reading and really thinking about what you may have meant by the textual description in your question) to restart a conversation about it, this may have been a different conversation.

Answer (score 0):

> When using natural numbers as array index, will `for (VAR in ARRAY)`
> iterate in the correct order?

GNU `AWK` manual's [Scanning an Array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html) says about such `for`

> The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this
> statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array
> elements within `awk` and in standard `awk` cannot be controlled or
> changed. This can lead to problems if new elements are added to *array*
> by statements in the loop body; it is not predictable whether the `for`
> loop will reach them. Similarly, changing *var* inside the loop may
> produce strange results. It is best to avoid such things.
>
> As a point of information, `gawk` sets up the list of elements to be
> iterated over before the loop starts, and does not change it. But not
> all `awk` versions do so.

So if question pertains to GNU `AWK` answer is that there is some order imposed, which as explained in [Controlling Scanning](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) might be changed (selected), however if it pertains to other `awk` versions you must not assume certain order of array traversal when using `for` without care.

Answer (score 0):

Both GNU awk and POSIX awk state that default array traversal is in **arbitrary** order.

From [OpenGroup POSIX awk documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/awk.html):

```
for (variable in array)

    which shall iterate, assigning each index of array to variable 
    in an unspecified order.
```

From [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal):

> By default, when a for loop traverses an array, the order is
> undefined, meaning that the awk implementation determines the order in
> which the array is traversed. This order is usually based on the
> internal implementation of arrays and will vary from one version of
> awk to the next.

Comment: The thing is that "ARRAY" is actually the wrong name for the thing that `awk` implements: An array is always ordered and indexed by an continuous sequence of indices. What awk implements is actually a hash table using array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can tell with absolute certainty is that in `mawk2`, for an array that was created via the `split()` function, and haven't had:

> ```
> 1. modifications to any of the array cell values,
> ```

> ```
> 2. increase in cell count, or
> ```

> ```
> 3. deletion of any existing cell, regardless of 
>    whether the remaining set of indices are contiguous or not
> ```

Then yes, the `for( idx in arr )` syntax would loop them in sequentially, and monotonically, ascending order.

Perform any one of those 3 actions, and the order goes random again. This is true *only* for `mawk-2`, not `mawk-1`.

Interesting thing about `mawk-1` though : set `WHINY_USERS=`  (with a blank value) as shell/environment variable that `mawk-1` can see, and the indices get sorted again, even if you add in floating point values in the middle of it:

- I inserted a new index of `sqrt(5)` using this chain as values :

  —- `OFMT CONVFMT FS OFS NF NR FNR` *(`the 611 is actually NF=6, NR=1, FNR=1, without spaces)`*

> ```
> date | WHINY_USERS= mawk '{ code…. }'
> ```

```
1 Thu | 2 Jul | 3 14 | 4 03:52:49 | 5 EDT | 6 2022 | 

1 Thu | 2 Jul | 2.23607 %.6g%.6g  611 | 3 14 | 4 03:52:49 | 5 EDT | 6 2022 |
```

It's even willing to sort in `INF`inities and `NaN`s for you numerically - negative infinities go to the left of index 1, while positive infinities and any `NaN`s go to right of highest index.

It becomes whacky when you put in something that's forced numeric conversion already, but it sorts it by `ASCII` anyway, e.g. a hex constant:

> ```
>                __[+"0xABCD"] **here**
>                                      \
>  1 Thu | 2 Jul | 3 14 | 4 04:01:15 | 43981 %.6g%.6g  611 | 5 EDT | 6 2022 |
> ```

Even the absolute smallest denormalized number in double-precision floating point couldn't deter `mawk-1` from using `ASCII` to sort:

```
1 Thu | 2 Jul | 3 14 | 4 04:08:05 | 4.940656436502 ... 4733973e-324 %.6g%.250g  611 | 5 EDT | 6 2022 |
```